# Was there a particular reason for 2012/2013's rise in movies about Abraham Lincoln?

Tags: abraham-lincoln-vampire-hunter, killing-lincoln, lincoln

In the last two years there have seemed to be an unusual amount of movies about Abraham Lincoln:

- [Killing Lincoln](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2299248/?ref_=fn_al_tt_8) (2013)
- [Lincoln](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443272/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (2012)
- [Abraham Lincoln: Vampire Hunter](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1611224/?ref_=fn_al_tt_4) (2012)
- [Abraham Lincoln vs Zombies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2246549/?ref_=fn_al_tt_9) (2012)

The last one certainly is not as big a movie as the other three. Still, compared to how many Lincoln movies have been made before 2012 (I could count 4 and 1 mini series, all spread over more than 60 years of movie history), that seems like a lot.

Is this just a random coincidence or is there some reason why making movies about Abe Lincoln is currently 'in'?

Comment: This sounds like a question asking for speculation. Any answers can be only guesses at best--unless there is some conspiracy that's uncovered.

Comment: I am not asking for speculation. I am asking for a logical reason for this development. This might be hard facts (like a statement from one of the movies creators) or a deduction based on hard facts and common sense (like the answer from wbogacz). I don't see how this is more speculative than any analysis question for example.

Comment: "A statement from one of the movie creators" would not answer your question for the "rise" in such movies--it would only answer the question for *one* movie. This is why I say a conspiracy would be necessary for any answer to be fact-based.

Comment: Not sure why you think there has to be a conspiracy if those movies all were made because of a common reason or event. I think the answer below shows pretty well that there is something special about the current year that was likely to ignite a hightened interest in Abraham Lincoln. Of course you may never know for sure if that was the reason or not, the same way you may never know for sure if [Vincent Vega shot Marvin on purpose](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3187/did-vincent-vega-shoot-marvin-on-purpose). I don't see why that makes the topic less worth exploring.

Comment: The only way multiple, otherwise independent events can happen for a common factual and provable reason, is if the perpetrators of said events are conspiring together. In other words, the only factual way to prove that all the movies came out for the same reason, is to show that they were all orchestrated by the same person or group of people. Since that group of people is not publicly known (due to them having been created by competing companies), it must be a conspiracy. Any other answer can be only speculation.

Comment: So you are saying that the 150th anniversary of the battle of Gettysburg is part of a conspiracy? I am not following your logic, but you surely are entitled to your own opinion. If you think this kind of question is a bad fit for the page in general I would suggest moving the discussion to Meta.

Comment: I'm saying that nobody can prove that the 150th anniversary of Gettysburg is the reason. This answer is speculation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, Abe Lincoln's war was the U.S. Civil War, and his greatest speech is undeniably the [Gettysburg Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettysburg_Address), about [the most costly battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Gettysburg), in casualties, of that war. Gettysburg, Pennsylvania is currently memorializing the battle, which occured June 30 - July 3, 1863, the 150th anniversary of the National Cemetery, and Lincoln's speech of November 19, 1863. If any treatment deserves to be made about Lincoln, it's got to be now - 2013. This includes books, movies, television, plays, virtually anything. I expect there to be other treatments right through 2015 - the 150th anniversary of his assassination.

This will flesh out this answer to provide a broader reason for Lincoln-mania in the current timeframe.

1. Lincoln's birth year was 1809, his 200th birthday would have been February 12, 2009. A new Lincoln Presidential Library was opened to commemorate in 2009.
2. Lincoln's first term as President started in 1861, its 150th anniversary of inauguration would have been March (inaugurations began in January much later), 2011.
3. The Confederacy of Southern States was formed, indicating their intention to secede from the United States, in 1861, between the time of Lincoln's election, but before his occupancy of the White House. This move was found to be illegal.
4. The Confederacy started the Civil War by attacking Fort Sumter in April 1861, and the war lasted throughout Lincoln's terms of office until his assassination, then through into the first month of Ulysses Grant's administration, to end in May 1865. The 150th anniversary of the war's battles encompass the years 2011 - 2015. Many current memorial events are happening throughout the battlefields in the United States.
5. Lincoln's Emancipation Proclamation was declared on September 22, 1862, to free the slaves effective January 1, 1863. The 150th anniversary of its enactment just occured in January 2013.
6. The Battle of Gettysburg, PA, June 30 - July 3, 1863, the most deadly of the war, and the northernmost battle (occuring deep within Union territory).
7. Lincoln's Gettysburg Address in November, 1863 to dedicate the new National Cemetery there, is considered one of the greatest political speeches.
8. Lincoln was re-elected in a landslide in 1864, and was inaugurated for his second term March, 1865.
9. In early April, 1865, Lincoln declares his intention to give voting rights to black people, inciting John Wilkes Booth to plan his assassination.
10. Lincoln's assassination occured one month after his second term commenced, the night of April 14, 1865, his death declared in the early morning hours of April 15th. The 150th anniversary of this event will occur in 2015.

Comment: Wow!! Excellent clarification. Did not know that!